# Why we need to create shapes if i need a little border radius for the buttons?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, android-shape, material-components-android

For example in `CSS` i will be using the property `border-radius: 10px`. So this single property saves me from extra overhead.

I searched all over the internet and found that all are doing shapes in android. Why in android we need to go for shapes (extra overhead) to make a button having a rounded corners and so on. Why shapes concept was created in android. If there is `Button` then there should also be the border radius kind of property.

Don't you think that the android development support is incomplete?

Whats the story behind this? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This question is feels the same as Why Kotlin has come if there is already Java. @Sunny All the platforms are having cool features some and limitations. You only have one case that's why it is looking to you as Improper Solution. but when you will dive in that there are numbers of advantages of using shapes.

Comment: but at least they should provide a full possible options `attributes` for a component. In this case the attribute is `border radius`.

Comment: There is no doubt that shapes has many advantages but your question is considerable.

Comment: You are having multiple options like **stroke** as a border and **radius** is as it is in shapes. there are some other attributes also. they made the whole these things included in one shapefile. that's not sound cool?

Comment: Can you please provide a detailed answer professionally, so we will keep this question for future android folks!!!

Comment: we don't normally allow "why" questions.  Just sayin'

Comment: @Sunny this property exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points made in the comments seem to partially answer your question but I just wanted to point out that it doesn't seem you are comparing apples to apples. HTML and XML are declarative languages while CSS is a style sheet language.

You'd be able to use HTML to make a button but would not be able to style it and add a corner as you mentioned.

When seen this way it makes sense why XML allows us to style components such as Buttons using shapes and drawables in general. This may not be the actual reason but the way I see it is that XML tries to cover what HTML and CSS do together and the "extra overhead" is simply what CSS would have done in web dev.

Would love to hear other opinions, though.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @Kevin.

Comment: I pointed `CSS` just for the sake of example, which provides full support for designing the `HTML` elements.

Comment: @Kevin - Your words `HTML and XML are declarative languages while CSS is a style sheet language.` washed all the confusions. Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 0):

> If there is Button then there should also be the border radius kind of property.

And there is! And it is very simple to use.
Just use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) in the official [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) with the **`app:cornerRadius`** attribute.

Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="BUTTON"
        app:cornerRadius="8dp"
        ../>
```

[image]

And you can also use this value globally in your app, adding this item in your theme.

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
     ....
     <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/myButtonStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="myButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="cornerRadius">8dp</item>
  </style>
```